# How to get the pixel value in a grayscale image

Tags: java, image, pixel, grayscale

I have a BufferedImage which is of TYPE_BYTE_GRAY and I need to get the pixel value at x,y. I know I can't use getRGB as it returns the wrong color model so how do I go about it? Many thanks!

Comment: What do u mean by getRGB returns the wrong color model? what is returning it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get `java.awt.image.Raster` from `BufferedImage` by invoking `getData()` method.

Then use

```
int getSample(int x, int y, int b)
```

on received object, where b is the color channel (where each color is represented by 8 bits).

For gray scale

```
b = 0.
```

For RGB image

```
b = 0 ==>> R channel,
b = 1 ==>> G channel,
b = 2 ==>> B channel.
```

Comment: Having looked at these methods this looks like the likely way to do it. It seems that int b is the "band" of the raster, I'm not overly sure what this means, and believe me I have looked online. I assume given that I have a grayscale image, it only has one band, and thus I want b to equal 0?

Comment: Fantastic thank you. I've implemented it and I'm getting much more sane results :-)

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you looking for is the math to get a one number to represent the Gray scale in that RGB, there are few diff ways, follow some of them:

> The lightness method averages the most prominent and least prominent
>   colors: (max(R, G, B) + min(R, G, B)) / 2.
>
> The average method simply averages the values: (R + G + B) / 3.
>
> The luminosity method is a more sophisticated version of the average
>   method. It also averages the values, but it forms a weighted average
>   to account for human perception. We’re more sensitive to green than
>   other colors, so green is weighted most heavily. The formula for
>   luminosity is 0.21 R + 0.71 G + 0.07 B.

Reference : http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/08/24/algorithms-convert-color-grayscale/

Comment: Okay thanks I'll look into that. However surely seeing as my image is ALREADY in grayscale there must be a simple way to get the pixel values straight from the image?

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you have a BufferedImage named grayImg whose type is TYPE_BYTE_GRAY

```
int width = grayImg.getWidth();

int height = grayImg.getHeight();

byte[] dstBuff = ((DataBufferByte) grayImg.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

Then the gray value at (x,y) would simply be:

```
dstBuff[x+y*width] & 0xFF;
```

Comment: the correct math would be dstBuff[y+x*width] & 0xFF;